# has_many through association error while relating users and projects

Tags: ruby, activerecord, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I have used has_many :through association for many-to-many relationship between two models namely user and project, but it seems as there is some mistake in it, as the queries which worked well in many-to-one relationship is throwing errors. Can someone check it please! The schema file is as below:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_12_19_170114) do

  create_table "project_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_project_users_on_project_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_project_users_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "picture"
    t.string "title"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_projects_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.integer "enroll"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

The user.rb file includes the code:

class User < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :project_users
        has_many :projects, through: :project_users
def feed
    projects
  end
end

```
The project.rb file has the code:

    class Project < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :project_users
      has_many :users, :through => :project_users
```

The project_user.rb file has the code:

```
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project, foreign_key: true
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true
end
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @project = current_user.projects.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
```

The error is thrown by the code:

```
<% if @user.projects.any? %>
    <h3>Projects (<%= @user.projects.count() %>)</h3>
```

The error is:

```
 SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: project_users.true: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "project_users" ON "projects"."id" = "project_users"."true" WHERE "project_users"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?
```

Comment: Edit your question to add the relevant parts of the models, the code that throws the error, and (of course) the exact error message.

Comment: What error does it throw? It's quite basic information to debug.

Comment: Remove `foreign_key: true` foreign key is for the name of an unconventional foreign key which is not the case in your association

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible worded question, as the comments have suggested, please include error messages otherwise it's impossible to debug.

At a glance, I can see the following issues in your schema:

1. Tables are named in plural form, e.g. `project_users`
2. Foreign keys are in singular form, e.g. `user_id`
3. Use the `t.references :user` helper instead of `t.integer :user_id`. You can then pass `index: true, foreign_key: true` options to setup indices and foreign keys.

Comment: The schema includes exactly that. Strangely it also includes `project_user` (not pluralized) version of the table.  However the rails convention for a HABM table would be `projects_users` (both plural) indicating that the relationship is unilateral

Comment: Check the migration when you added the ProjectUser table. It should be creating a table named `project_users` not `project_user`. You can see in the error message that rails is looking for the plural form.

Comment: I have rolled back the migration and added the new migration, have updated the question with the current schema file. but still it's throwing errors.

Comment: Remove the `foreign_key: true` options from your ProjectUser class. That was an option in your migration, not the model.

Answer (score 0):

**foreign_key: true**  is causing your error.
The ProjectsUser model should look like this

```
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :user
end
```

The error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: project_users.true` is trying to explain that the way you have set up the model has sqlite looking for a column called "true" on the ProjectUser. As the names of the foreign_key columns ar the same as the class names of the objects associated (projects and users) you don't need to specifically tell ActiveRecord what the foreign_key is called. It will correctly assume that it is looking for project_id, and user_id